# How to set another version of Python as a default for virtualenv.exe? ( not for existing virtual env )

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to download and deploy Stable Diffusion on my computer. It requires Python 3.10.6, which I have already installed. I changed the paths in the global variables so that the newer version of Python is used by default.

The Stable Diffusion installer uses virtualenv.exe module ( for creating venv for itself, i guess ) which can't turn on because it's trying to run through an old version of Python that I've already uninstalled.

I need the virtualenv.exe module to automatically work through the new version of Python when it is called, not the old one which is long gone.

Comment: Where does the `virtualenv.exe` come from? Did you install it yourself? Typically if you want `virtualenv.exe` to create environments for Python 3.10 by default then this `virtualenv.exe` must be created/installed with Python 3.10.